# When sending a JavaScript object with socket.io, does it encode it as JSON or send it in a binary format?

Tags: javascript, json, sockets, websocket, socket.io

For example, in the following code:

```
io.emit('foo', { a: 5, b: 5.5, c: "5" });
```

Does it encode the entire thing as a JSON object before sending, i.e.

```
'{a:5,b:5.5,c:"5"}'
```

or does it use a binary format in which the integer 5 occupies 4 bytes (32 bits), the float 5.5 occupies 8 bytes (64 bits), and the string "5" occupies 1 byte plus a null terminator (16 bits)?

I'm asking this because I'm trying to save on bandwidth for low-latency, frequent socket.io communication over a 4G/LTE connection.

Answer (score 0):

It encodes it as a binary string. See the [socket.io-protocol](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol) library.